# Replacing Latex Expressions With Representations

Tags: emacs, latex

I use emacs to edit latex in markdown documents, and I'm curious as to whether there would be a way to have text render in emacs more in line with what will be displayed in my .tex. For example, if I want a numbered list, I do something like:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item{TEST}
\end{enumerate}
```

What I would really like is to be able to type:

```
\begin{enumerate}
```

and for emacs to display something like:

```
1.
```

while behind the scenes the raw text still reads:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item{}
\end{enumerate}
```

This might be more trouble than it's worth, but could be neat if I could get it to work. The essense of what I'm looking for is something that sits between the raw text and the displayed text, and formats it according to some regex.

Comment: Consider using [whizzytex](http://cristal.inria.fr/whizzytex/) instead

Comment: The reason I put it here is because I'm trying to be a little more broad than just tex. The root of my question is: is there an expression in lisp I can use which, when I type `x` it displays `y`, while retaining `x` in the background for rendering. If I have that tool, I can write the mode to do what I want.

Comment: What you have written in your comment is not clear from  your question, I suggest you edit your question to make it much clearer what you want to know.